# print n*m matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB I'm printing a very large matrix this way:

```
fid = fopen('c:\\OUTPUT.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%f\t',T');
fclose(fid);
```

But this is not right! I want to print it like this:(`\t` between them and `\n` at the end of row)

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

I searched and found If it was 3*3 this was fine:

```
fprintf(fid,'%f %f %f\n',T');
```

But I in my case size change...

Comment: You could just chain the `fprintf` commands like, `for ii=1:N; fprintf(fid,'%f',T(ii)); if(ii~=N) fprintf(fid,'\t') end end fprintf(fid,'\n');  or just save to a `mat` file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the very simple

```
fprintf([repmat('%f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], A');
```

You will have one superfluous tab `\t` at the end of each line, though:

```
>> A = magic(5)

A =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

>> fprintf([repmat('%f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], A')
17.000000   24.000000   1.000000    8.000000    15.000000   % oh, a tab
23.000000   5.000000    7.000000    14.000000   16.000000   % oh, a tab 
4.000000    6.000000    13.000000   20.000000   22.000000   % oh, a tab
10.000000   12.000000   19.000000   21.000000   3.000000    % oh, a tab
11.000000   18.000000   25.000000   2.000000    9.000000    % oh, a tab
```

To print the output to a file, just use

```
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], A')
```

Comment: where should I address txt file?!

Comment: @bunNyBug Use `fprintf(fid, …)`

Comment: @Lumen - Any way to eliminate last empty new line?

Comment: Here's an alternative that avoids the extra tab: `fprintf(fid, ['%f' repmat('\t%f', 1, size(A, 2)-1) '\n'], A')`

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to look at [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)

You can set delimiters, precision, etc.

```
dlmwrite('myfile.txt', M, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', 6)
```

Where `M` is your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

*To add to an already helpful and accepted answer by @Lumen*

You can eliminate the superfluous tab using `strrep` to look for a tab preceding a newline character, `\t\n` an replacing with just, `\n`.

Therefore,

```
fprintf([repmat('%f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], A');
```

Becomes:

```
fprintf(strrep([repmat('%f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'],'\t\n','\n'), A');
```