# Why does it appear that dlmwrite is ignoring decimals and NaNs when writing to a csv file?

Tags: matlab, csv

Let me provide some background information before I describe my problem.  I originally wrote a function that wrote several values to an excel file.  Because of the formatting of the data, I used xlswrite to generate a fairly nice spreadsheet.  However, I needed to use my program on a PC without excel, so I adapted my function to use dlmwrite.  Since the variables don't necessarily have the same dimensions, I wrote a function to resolve these dimensions in order to put them into a single matrix - that is, if they weren't the same length, extra rows of NaN would be added.

When I was testing this function with small data sets, everything was working well (decimals were showing up, NaNs were being entered, etc.).  Here's the function:

```
function dlmWriteKt(fileNameExtra, time, rawMotorData, usCount, tach, rpmData, angVelocity, r, angAccelLine, maxAccel, inertia, maxT, phaseResist, maxCurrent, kT)


%Generate a filename
      fileName = ['Test_' fileNameExtra '_' num2str(time(1)) '_' num2str(time(2)) '_' num2str(time(3)) '.csv'];

%Construct a matrix whose columns correspond to each variable

    %Store the first column: rawMotorData
       M = rawMotorData;

    %Store the second column: usCount
       M = resolveSize(M, usCount);

    %Store the third column: tach
       M = resolveSize(M, tach);

    %Store the fourth column: rpmData
       M = resolveSize(M, rpmData);

    %Store the fifth column: angVelocity
       M = resolveSize(M, angVelocity);

    %Store the sixth column: r
       M = resolveSize(M, r);

    %Store the seventh column: angAccelLine
       M = resolveSize(M, angAccelLine);

   %Store the eighth column: maxAccel
       M = resolveSize(M, maxAccel);

   %Store the ninth column: inertia
       M = resolveSize(M, inertia);

    %Store the tenth column: maxT
       M = resolveSize(M, maxT);

    %Store the eleventh column: phaseResitst
       M = resolveSize(M, phaseResist);

    %Store the twelth column
       M = resolveSize(M, maxCurrent);

    %Store the thirteenth column: kT
       M = resolveSize(M, kT);

    %Write a csv file
       dlmwrite(fileName, M);
end

function combinedData = resolveSize(currentMatrix, newColumn)
   %This function appends new rows if needed to either the currentMatrix or
   %newColumn in order to concatenate the two.

    %Declare local variables
       numColumnsMatrix = 0;
       numColumnsNew = 0;

    %Determine the number of columns of each matrix
       s = size(currentMatrix);
       numColumnsMatrix = s(1);

       t = size(newColumn);
       numColumnsNew = t(1);

    %Determine how many rows to append to either matrix
       difference = numColumnsMatrix - numColumnsNew;

    %Determine which matrix requires appended rows

        if(difference > 0)
            %Add rows to newColumn
                addRow(1:difference) = NaN;
                newColumn = [newColumn; addRow'];
                combinedData = [currentMatrix newColumn];
                return;

        else if(difference < 0)
                %Add rows to currentMatrix
                    %Determine if there are multiple columns of
                    %currentMatrix.
                        if(s(2) > 1)
                            addRow = ones(abs(difference), s(2));
                            addRow(:,:) = NaN;
                            currentMatrix = [currentMatrix; addRow];
                            combinedData = [currentMatrix newColumn];
                            return;

                        else
                            addRow(1:abs(difference)) = NaN;
                            currentMatrix = [currentMatrix; addRow'];
                            combinedData = [currentMatrix newColumn];
                            return;

                        end
            else
                %The column dimension of both matrices match
                    combinedData = [currentMatrix newColumn];
                    return;
            end
        end
end
```

This function was working fine when I was testing it in the command line.  However, when I integrated into my larger program, I started losing all the decimals and NaNs.  Thinking that the precision wasn't high enough, I changed dlmwrite to dlmwrite('fileName', M, 'precision', '%.6f'). The only change was that 24.0 changed to 24.000000! Still no decimal. Also, all the NaNs were represented as 0.000000.

I know that the issue is not with my larger program. Nothing has changed other than this function. I verified that the parameters being passed do indeed contain decimals. It's during the write that I lose this information.

I've included a link to some of the data I've been getting in case anyone wants to see it: [Spreadsheet Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25RK6D_tnM_TDhtcF82Wm1fUWs/edit?usp=sharing). Considering the last column, the first row should be a value like 0.00478, and all the rows below should be NaN.

Any constructive input would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having some trouble reproducing this problem. I've created some big random arrays (more than 100000 elements). I'm using matlab 2012.
I'm getting all the decimals, and the NaNs.

Maybe you could try writing to a file using fprintf like stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032549/print-nm-matrix-in-matlab

Comment: @RuiSilva Unfortunately, I'm having the same problem. I've generated my own data to try and replicate the problem outside of my program. Regardless of what I try, I can't reproduce the results I'm seeing. I keep going back to my program and see if it is causing the problem, but nothing stands out. Before I execute dlmwrite, I print out the variables to the command line, and the decimals are intact.

Comment: Can you provide a link with the data your program is generating? I might be able to give it a look and see if I also get the problem.

Comment: @RuiSilva It should still be active in my post, but just in case, here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25RK6D_tnM_TDhtcF82Wm1fUWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's the data you get from running the matlab code you posted, right? I was referring to the original data (the columns you pass as argument). If you save your workspace as a .mat file I will try to give it a look.

Comment: Yes. I will grab one of the files and provide a link.

Comment: @RuiSilva Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25RK6D_tnM_cXpMVXlXNG5GNWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just ran the function with that data you provided, and everything went as expected. dlmwrite wrote the file with the decimals and NaNs.

Comment: So did I - everything worked. I don't understand what is going on.