# Matlab command window output of matrix values does not match output in file

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a very large matrix and want to check it on screen before I continue to use it. Now, when displaying it, the values are completely wrong (off by a factor of 100), but when I print them to a file everything is fine. (And here I would have loved to post a picture of this, but I don't have enough reputation...) Here's the code:

```
disp(bigMatrix) %does not work the way I expected

for i = 1:size(bigMatrix, 1)                     %from here to
    for j = 1:size(bigMatrix, 2)                 %
        fprintf(fileOne, '%f', bigMatrix(i,j));  %
        fprintf(fileOne, '\t');                  %
    end                                          %
    fprintf(fileOne, '\r\n');                    %
end                                              %here everything is perfect
```

So, in my file I have a 1 at the end of each column where the disp() function (or just typing the name of my matrix) gives me a 0.0010. All the other values are wrong as well, so it might be a formatting issue. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to save a matrix to file. Why not use the `save` function?

Comment: Please verify my solution or kindly let me know if anything's wrong!

Comment: Jup, I'm on it, sorry, was lunch time over here...^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a formatting issue: Because the matrix was so big, I couldn't scroll up to its beginning where Matlab's standard format

```
format short
```

declared my result to be

```
bigMatrix =

             1.0e+03 *

              [...bigMatrix...]
```

So the values looked wrong at the bottom although they weren't. Changing the format to

```
format short g
```

does the trick.

Comment: Dang okay, can you still up-vote my answer for the detail/effort of the post? XD

Comment: @krisdestruction sure, you just gave me enough reputation to do so.... :D ah, nope, it requires 15, so....as soon as I have them^^

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to save the variable name into a readable format, you should look into the `dlmwrite` function. It saves your variable with a delimiter, a space or a tab in your case.

```
bigMatrix = rand(10);
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter',' ');
```

If you wish to delimit using tab, you can use the following line

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter','\t')
```

If you wish to further specify the precision you can use the following code to specify a `precision = 3` sig figs.

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter','\t','precision',3)
```

Furthermore, you can specify a constant precision using a string for a constant decimal precision. Specifying `4f` will give you what you see in `format short` while `16f` will give you what you see in `format long`.

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter','\t','precision','%.4f');
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter','\t','precision','%.16f');
```

Console results

```
0.0157    0.8161    0.1660    0.8044    0.7012    0.8915    0.6966    0.2325    0.9770    0.6212
0.5967    0.1195    0.3072    0.6632    0.5709    0.3407    0.5644    0.4358    0.5343    0.1799
0.3570    0.2627    0.4324    0.2399    0.8350    0.4752    0.1126    0.5609    0.8926    0.5254
0.8675    0.6808    0.5898    0.7436    0.3731    0.5500    0.9843    0.7279    0.9430    0.0010
0.0743    0.4527    0.7377    0.2043    0.2759    0.0786    0.9285    0.3956    0.4404    0.3718
0.3304    0.4124    0.4244    0.0284    0.5514    0.1419    0.5662    0.3812    0.8652    0.9084
0.0137    0.2696    0.1927    0.3641    0.2758    0.9919    0.1418    0.4953    0.2369    0.4871
0.6338    0.6510    0.0933    0.4455    0.6999    0.0452    0.9040    0.0693    0.5381    0.2402
0.3475    0.2850    0.0704    0.1310    0.4020    0.8573    0.9005    0.0485    0.1248    0.4577
0.6318    0.9094    0.8535    0.8341    0.3268    0.7237    0.3242    0.6747    0.6252    0.0885
```

File results

```
0.0157  0.8161  0.1660  0.8044  0.7012  0.8915  0.6966  0.2325  0.9770  0.6212
0.5967  0.1195  0.3072  0.6632  0.5709  0.3407  0.5644  0.4358  0.5343  0.1799
0.3570  0.2627  0.4324  0.2399  0.8350  0.4752  0.1126  0.5609  0.8926  0.5254
0.8675  0.6808  0.5898  0.7436  0.3731  0.5500  0.9843  0.7279  0.9430  0.0010
0.0743  0.4527  0.7377  0.2043  0.2759  0.0786  0.9285  0.3956  0.4404  0.3718
0.3304  0.4124  0.4244  0.0284  0.5514  0.1419  0.5662  0.3812  0.8652  0.9084
0.0137  0.2696  0.1927  0.3641  0.2758  0.9919  0.1418  0.4953  0.2369  0.4871
0.6338  0.6510  0.0933  0.4455  0.6999  0.0452  0.9040  0.0693  0.5381  0.2402
0.3475  0.2850  0.0704  0.1310  0.4020  0.8573  0.9005  0.0485  0.1248  0.4577
0.6318  0.9094  0.8535  0.8341  0.3268  0.7237  0.3242  0.6747  0.6252  0.0885
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for different ways of saving my data or adjusting my precision, I'm just confused by the fact that the two outputs are not the same. The data in my file shows the expected values, but the on-screen output doesn't and I have no idea why. A colleague suggested it might have to do with the format, i.e. that the command window might use a different notation (like +e or sth.), but I don't understand why this never happened before and also why it doesn't say so.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion
`dlmwrite('myFile.txt',bigMatrix,'delimiter','\t')`
and my text file still contains the correct values, but now it's unreadable for me. I encountered the same problem with
`fprintf(fileOne, [repmat('%.6f\t', 1, size(bigMatrix, 2)) '\n'], bigMatrix');` suggested here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032549/print-nm-matrix-in-matlab]
which is why I went back to using a very basic fprintf for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just found the answer to my problem. Now I'll just wait for two days until I can accept it... :)