# dlmwriter puts space between each character

Tags: matlab, text-files, export-to-text

I am trying to write a quite large binary array to text file. My data's dimension is `1 X 35,000` and it is like :

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 .... 0 0 0 1
```

What I want to do is first add a string in the beginning of this array let's say ROW1 and then export this array to a text file with space delimiter.

What I have tried so far:

```
fww1 = strcat({'ROW_'},int2str(1));
fww2 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str((full(array(1,:)))'))');

new = [fww1 fww2];

dlmwrite('text1.txt', new,'delimiter',' ','-append', 'newline', 'pc');
```

As a result of this code I got:

```
R O W _ 1 0 0 0 0 1 ....
```

How can I get it as below:

```
ROW_1 0 0 0 0 1 ....
```

Comment: The documentation for [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) explicitly states it's for *numeric* data. Writing delimited mixed data is not one of MATLAB's strong suits. Use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) and [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html), similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032549/print-nm-matrix-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way of writing to text files is using `fprintf`. There is a bit of a learning curve (you'll need to figure out the format specifiers, i.e. the `%d` etc.) but it's definitely worth it, and many other programming languages have some implementation of `fprintf`.

So for your problem, let's do the following. First, we'll open a file for writing.

```
fid = fopen('text1.txt', 'wt');
```

The `'wt'` means that we'll open the file for writing in text mode. Next, let's write this string you wanted:

```
row_no = 1;
fprintf(fid, 'ROW_%d', row_no);
```

The `%d` is a special character that tells `fprintf` to replace it with a decimal representation of the given number. In this case it behaves a lot like `int2str` (maybe `num2str` is a better analogy, since it also works on non-integers).

Next, we'll write the row of data. Again, we'll use `%d` to specify that we want a decimal representation of the boolean array.

```
fprintf(fid, ' %d', array(row_no,:));
```

A couple thing to note. First, we the format specifier also includes a space in front of every number, so that takes care of the delimiter. Second, we only specified a single format but an array of numbers. When faced with this, `fprintf` will just go on repeating the format until it runs out of numbers.

Next, we'll write a newline to indicate the end of the row (`\n` is one of the special characters recognized by `fprintf`):

```
fprintf(fid, '\n');
```

If you have more lines to write, you can put a for loop over these `fprintf` statements. Finally, we'll close the file so that the operating system knows we're done writing to it.

```
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks @user1877862 for this detailed and clear explanation!